# Acknowledgements in an industry-sponsored dissertation

Tags: mathematics, industry, thesis, acknowledgement

I am a doing a dissertation funded by a company and my dissertation is basically a report of my progress on the problem they have given me. I have an **academic supervisor**, an **industry contact** who has given me occasional guidance and basically the company itself who sponsored it, to acknowledge.

- Should I acknowledge the industrial sponsorship the same way one would acknowledge a government grant?
- Also, Since this is a mathematics dissertation, It is written in First person plural: "We do this we do that". For the acknowledgements section, should I use 3rd person to keep it formal: "The author would like to..." or first person singular: "I would like to thank"
- Finally, I think the order should be sponsorship, academic adviser, and lastly the industry contact. Is that the right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can speak from a similar experience.  Many moons ago, when I was completing my Honours research (yes, this was and still is considered postgraduate), I was sponsored by a company (mining and economic geology). With the acknowledgements, I was told to give my thanks in the order:

- Academic and industrial supervisors by name and affiliation.  These are your first points of contact and did the most of work with you.
- The company for the sponsorship.
- Then friends, family and/or pets.

This is not an opinion, but experience.

But, having said that, I would *strongly* recommend that you ask both advisors what is expected as @seteropere suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I would say generally there are no perfect settings for acknowledgements. It all depends to your university dissertation rules. If the thesis/dissertation booklet does not cover the way acknowledgement should be stated then its up to you.

Comment: Well yeah the lack of standard rules was the reason I came here for opinions... :)

Comment: @Shb this site is **not** a place for soliciting opinions. Questions must be of the form that can receive expert answers.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers yes, but expert answers can actually be well-informed opinions… maybe there are no standard rules in university guidelines, but there are customs, expectations, etc. all of which form an important part of academic life